# Add suggestions to search box, not happening

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, query

I configured my search box for using query suggestion in SharePoint 2010.
Unfortunately after 6 search of a term and runing the job `Prepare query suggestions` and `Logging query`, it doesn't appear in the suggestion of the search box.

Do you know how I can add terms without using PowerShell?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention your SharePoint version, but **for 2013**:

> Open Central Administration > Service Applications > Search Service Application
>
> From the left hand side choose the Query Suggestions link. [..]
>
> Enable the Show check box and choose the Import from text file option.
>
> Create a text file like this, containing your suggestions:
>
> [image]
>
> Upload the text file and click OK
>
> Now run the `Prepare query suggestions`job

This answer is in great part based / borrowed from [Jean Paul](http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2014/04/03/enable-query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-2013-search/)

**For 2010**, they are indeed created when typed in 6 times in the search box. But make sure that the search results webpart is configured to show them:

> To configure query suggestions
>
> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a site owner on the Search Center site.
> 2. On the Search Center site home page, click Site Actions, and then click Edit page.
> 3. On the Search Box Web Part menu, click Edit Web Part.
> 4. Expand the Query Suggestions node.
> 5. Make sure that the Show query suggestions box is selected. If you want to turn off query suggestions, clear the Show query suggestions check box.
> 6. If required, change the following settings:
>
>    - Minimum prefix length: The number of letters the user must type before query suggestions are displayed.
>    - Suggestion delay (in milliseconds): The number of milliseconds to elapse before query suggestions are displayed.
>    - Number of suggestions to display: The number of query suggestions to display in the list.
> 7. Click OK.

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh148698(v=office.14).aspx).

Also make sure that `Query Logging` is enabled in the Search Service Application

The only other way is to add them by PowerShell I'm afraid.

Comment: i don't have access to central admin. i'm in sandbox solution. I read when you search 6 times a term and running the job, the suggestions should be added but it doesn't work

Comment: How can you run timer jobs without having access to Central Admin? It does not matter how many times you search if the checkbox `Show search suggestions` is not enabled in the Search Service Application

Comment: i'm in a test environment so i can run the job but in production i've to tell to the administrator what he should change. Where is "show search suggestion"? i add printscreen of central admin search  (I'm in sharepoint 2010)

Comment: Well that makes most of my answer useless. Updated it for 2010, where you are more limited

Comment: Don't you know how SharePoint consider a term can be add to the suggestions? because clicking 6 times on a result or a search and then run job doens't work

Comment: For 2010, you need to use PowerShell, which you told us before that you can not. HAve you made sure the Result webpart is correct?

Comment: when i look this link, it explaines that after 6 click of the search result you should have the suggestion after running job

Comment: Still, I keep asking: Have you configured the webpart?

Comment: yes the checkbox "Show query suggestions " is enable. i tested with added some in powershell and i see them

Comment: Can you ask your SP Admin to make sure that "Query Logging" is enabled in the Search service application? That is a service responsible for recording and analyzing user searches

Comment: it is, because it's on my test environnement and i restart both jobs. Are there a way to manipulate suggestions in code client? sharepoint.client assembly like SP.somethingForSuggestion

Comment: This is not a job but a setting on the search application itself. There is no way to add search suggestions from the client side, it is the Query Logging that analyzes the searches and from that creates suggestions

Comment: it's enable and i run the job too after 6 clicks on a search result. It seems there are nothing to do without powershell and it sucks :-(

Comment: I get it to work in my environment following the above (making ~6 searches for the same keyword, clicking on the first search result. Then run "Logging Query", and when that is completed "Prepare Query Suggestions")

Comment: Did you configure something of particular for making it works? I did the same things of you without success

Comment: Nothing more than already said; the webpart and the Query Logging